How to remove the first blank page?
When compiling this document, the very first page is blank. I tried to remove with some trick like \vspace{} but it didn't work. I also check around here, and tried \let\cleardoublepage\clearpage but nothing. Can you please help me?
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=11mm}




\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{BR}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}

\usepackage{everysel}
\everymath{\color{BR}}
\everydisplay{\color{BR}}
\EverySelectfont{\color{black}}

%%%

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\(\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
\toprule
\text{Name-Surname} &  \text{ID} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(1\)}\phantom{A} &        \phantom{A}\text{C\(2\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(3\)}\phantom{A} &         \phantom{A}\text{C\(4\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(5\)}\phantom{A} &        \phantom{A}\text{C\(6\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(7\)}\phantom{A} &         \phantom{A}\text{C\(8\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(9\)}\phantom{A} &    \phantom{A}\text{C\(10\)}\phantom{A} & \Sigma 
\\ 
\midrule
\vspace{3mm}
\text{A.B.} & 0001185676 & 0.05 &  &  &  & \\ 
   \vspace{3mm}
\text{A.B.} & 0001181744 & 0.22 &  &  &  & \\ 
   \vspace{3mm}
\text{A.B.} & 0001180031 & 0.3 &  &  &  & \\ 
   \vspace{3mm}
 \bottomrule
\end{array}\)
\end{table}
\end{center}

The code is just a table with entries, it keeps going on, I cut it a bit.

don't put table inside center. I haven't checked if this causes the extra page, but it will definitely screw things up.

don't you get an error with this code? I can't reproduce the extra page, though.

You presumable don't want the content on your title page to float, so don't use a table environment.

... and don't use \vspace{3mm} to manually add spaces

@cfr It compiles without errors to me...

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for those advices! There are so many things I don't know

@Henry How do you compile your document? With overleaf or locally?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Locally, with TeXShop on Mac Os

@Henry In this case, your document should cause an error. First Misplaced \noalign. \bottomrule and then more errors because of the missing \end{document}

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz You're right about the \end{document}, I just didn't write it here (I forgot). But for the rest I don't get the other error...

I can't reproduce the additional page using your code, but I do get errors. You cannot use \vspace inside the array like this. Instead, adjust \arrayrulestretch and/or add space after \\  e.g. \\[1mm] or whatever.
In addition, never put a float such as table inside center. You don't want the material to float away here, so don't use table.
I am not sure I see the case for using array here rater than tabular, but the same principles apply either way.
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, margin=11mm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{everysel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\definecolor{BR}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}
\everymath{\color{BR}}
\everydisplay{\color{BR}}
\EverySelectfont{\color{black}}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
  \(\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \text{Name-Surname} &  \text{ID} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(1\)}\phantom{A} &        \phantom{A}\text{C\(2\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(3\)}\phantom{A} &         \phantom{A}\text{C\(4\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(5\)}\phantom{A} &        \phantom{A}\text{C\(6\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(7\)}\phantom{A} &         \phantom{A}\text{C\(8\)}\phantom{A} & \phantom{A}\text{C\(9\)}\phantom{A} &    \phantom{A}\text{C\(10\)}\phantom{A} & \Sigma
    \\[2.5mm]
    \midrule
    \text{A.B.} & 0001185676 & 0.05 &  &  &  & \\[2.5mm]
    \text{A.B.} & 0001181744 & 0.22 &  &  &  & \\[2.5mm]
    \text{A.B.} & 0001180031 & 0.3 &  &  &  & \\[2.5mm]
    \bottomrule
  \end{array}\)
\end{center}
\end{document}


Since everything else has failed, I used this and IT WORKED.
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}


I asked the question too early. In searching again and again, I found a solution so I thought to post it.
